# Thread won't stop using a button(Multithreading)

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to stop multiple threads using a stop button in another class. I tried using the boolean function in stopping a thread but it won't work. When the user click the stopbutton, the thread is still running, how do i fix this?

This is the main class

```
public class ElevatorSystem extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public static int currentFloor = 1;

    Thread ElevatorMove = null;
    Thread PeopleMove = null;
    static Thread RandomPeople = null;
    Thread MAIN_THREAD = new Thread(new Main_Thread());
    private Main_Thread mt = new Main_Thread();
    ...

    public ElevatorSystem() {
        initComponents();
        randWeight();
        this.setResizable(false);
        if(pplw.isEmpty())
            elev_weight = 0;
        else{
            for(int s:pplw)
                elev_weight += s;

        }
        RandomPeople = new Thread(new Randomize_People(EntryFloor1,EntryFloor2,EntryFloor3,EntryFloor4,EntryFloor5));
        RandomPeople.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY-1);
    //Start Adding peeoples
        RandomPeople.start();
    }

    ...
    private void btnStopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        //not working...
        if(MAIN_THREAD.isAlive()){
            try {
                mt.stopThread();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ElevatorSystem.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }else{
            this.setEnabled(false);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Thread Not Running!","Thread Not Running!",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            this.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }   
}
```

This is the threads

```
class Main_Thread implements Runnable{
    ....
    private final Object ElevatorSystem = new Object();
    private boolean pauseThreadFlag = false;

    Main_Thread(){

    }

    Main_Thread(
        JTextField EntryFloor1, JTextField ExitFloor1,
        JTextField EntryFloor2, JTextField ExitFloor2,
        JTextField EntryFloor3, JTextField ExitFloor3,
        JTextField EntryFloor4, JTextField ExitFloor4,
        JTextField EntryFloor5, JTextField ExitFloor5,
        JTextField Ceiling,

        JTextArea Elev1,   JPanel Elev1Container,

        String Elevator_Status, int currentFloor,int elev_weight, ArrayList pplw
    ){
        this.EntryFloor1 = EntryFloor1; this.ExitFloor1 = ExitFloor1;
        this.EntryFloor2 = EntryFloor2; this.ExitFloor2 = ExitFloor2;
        this.EntryFloor3 = EntryFloor3; this.ExitFloor3 = ExitFloor3;
        this.EntryFloor4 = EntryFloor4; this.ExitFloor4 = ExitFloor4;
        this.EntryFloor5 = EntryFloor5; this.ExitFloor5 = ExitFloor5;

        this.Elev1 = Elev1;
        this.Elev1Container = Elev1Container;

        this.Elevator_Status = Elevator_Status;
        this.currentFloor = currentFloor;

        this.elev_weight = elev_weight;

        this.pplw.addAll(pplw);
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running...");
        System.out.println("Inside Weight: "+pplw);
        while(true){
            checkForPaused();
            //whole process
       }
    }

    private void checkForPaused() {
       synchronized (ElevatorSystem) {
           while (pauseThreadFlag) {
               try {
                   ElevatorSystem.wait();
               } catch (Exception e) {}
           }
       }
    }

    public void stopThread() throws InterruptedException {
        pauseThreadFlag = true;
    }
}

class People_Move implements Runnable{
    ...
}

class Elevator_move_UP implements Runnable{
    ...
}

class Elevator_move_DOWN implements Runnable{
    ...
}

class Randomize_People implements Runnable{
    ...
}
```

Comment: And read about java naming conventions. Underbars only go into SOME_CONSTANT; but **not** into class names. And learn about arrays or lists - whenever you are starting to name variables a1, a2, ... and so on, you are doing something **wrong**. And of course, variable names start lowerCase. Violating such rules makes it hard for any java programmer to read your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two instances of `Main_Thread`:

```
Thread MAIN_THREAD = new Thread(new Main_Thread());
private Main_Thread mt = new Main_Thread();
```

You're stopping one, but observing the other.

```
if(MAIN_THREAD.isAlive()){
  try {
    mt.stopThread();
```

Simply use a single instance:

```
private Main_Thread mt = new Main_Thread();
Thread MAIN_THREAD = new Thread(mt);
```

---

You should also ensure that the update to `paused` in the stop method is visible in other threads. You should make the stop method `synchronized` (or use an `AtomicBoolean`, or use a proper way of signalling between threads, like a mutex or semaphore).

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple reasons why it does not work.

1. `ElevatorSystem.mt` is another instance of `Main_Thread` as the one used by `ElevatorSystem.MAIN_THREAD`.
2. I don't see that `MAIN_THREAD` is started anywhere.
3. The class `Main_Thread` expects it's flag `pauseThreadFlag` to be `false` for stopping, but `Main_Thread.stopThread` sets it to `true`.
4. `Main_Thread.checkForPaused` calls `wait`, but I don't see a place where it is waked up.
5. I don't see a reason why stopping `ElevatorSystem.MAIN_THREAD` should stop other threads, too.